# VBA - Highlighting a cell if it contains red text

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write/run a VBA macro that highlights all cells in a workbook that contain red font (although, ALL characters within a string in given cell may not be red). The macro I've come up with falls short in that it only highlights cells that contain ONLY red font. I want it to highlight cells that may contain black text as well as red text. Here's the macro I've come up with:
'''

```
Sub HighlightCell()
Set ws = Sheets("MySheet")
For r = 1 To 104
    For c = 1 To 36
        If (ws.Cells(r, c).Font.Color = 255) Then
            'set the desired color index
            ws.Cells(r, c).Interior.ColorIndex = 34
        End If
    Next c
Next r
End Sub
```

Is there a better macro to do this?
Thank you so much.

Comment: You need to loop over the cell's `Characters` collection and check the color of each character.

Comment: ^^^^ To speed things up, check if the cell's entire text is red, if not, check it is "null" (which basically means there is more than one colour), then loop over the characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```vb
Sub HighlightCell()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, c As Range, i As Long, v

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        Debug.Print "Checking sheet '" & ws.Name & "' in workbook '" & _
                     ws.Parent.Name & "'"

        For Each c In ws.Range("A1").Resize(104, 36).Cells
            v = c.Value
            If Not c.HasFormula And Not IsError(v) Then
                If Len(v) > 0 Then                        'if cell has any text
                    
                    If c.Font.Color = 255 Then            'all text is red ?
                        c.Interior.ColorIndex = 34
                    ElseIf IsNull(c.Font.Color) Then      'mixed font color?
                        For i = 1 To Len(c.Value)
                            If c.Characters(i, 1).Font.Color = 255 Then
                                c.Interior.ColorIndex = 34
                                Exit For                  'no need to check further
                            End If
                        Next i
                    End If
        
                End If 'has any text
            End If     'no formula, and does not contain an error value
        Next c
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. When I run this, I get run-time error '9' - subscript out of range. The debugger says line 4 (set ws) is the problem. Could you please clarify what should go in this line?

Comment: If the worksheet "MySheet" is in a different workbook from the one containing your code, then you will need to specify what workbook that is, or if it's in the active workbook then use `Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet")`

Comment: Can this macro be written to query the entire workbook? I'm actually not concerned about individual sheets.

Comment: See edit above.

Comment: Thanks again. I'm running this from VBAProject (PERSONAL.XSLB), and that edited code doesn't seem to work. I've adapted it to run correctly on individual sheets, but not on the entire workbook.

Comment: What does it do instead of work?  Do you get an error?  What happens or doesn't happen which is different from what you expect/want?

Comment: It doesn't give me an error, but it also doesn't highlight cells that contain red text. It seems to do nothing.

Comment: Added a debug.print above - let's check it's running against the correct sheets...

Comment: When running that macro as is (with ActiveWorkbook instead of ThisWorkbook), it gives me run-time error '13' (type mismatch). Debugger highlights this line:  "If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then                  'if cell has any text" 

When running with ThisWorkbook, there is no error, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: You may need to first check for `If Not IsError(c.Value)` before checking the font color (maybe also screen out any cells with formulas also)