# Macro issue on certain sheets

Tags: excel, vba

my macro, shown below, seems to work on some sheets but not others (within the same workbook). Any ideas as to why?

```
Sub HighlightCell()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, c As Range, i As Long

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet 1")     'input sheet name between quotes
    For Each c In ws.Range("A1").Resize(104, 36).Cells
        If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then                  'if cell has any text
            
            If c.Font.Color = 255 Or c.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then            'all text is red ?
                c.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 34
            ElseIf IsNull(c.Font.Color) Then      'mixed font color?
                For i = 1 To Len(c.Value)
                    If c.Characters(i, 1).Font.Color = 255 Then
                        c.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 34
                        Exit For                  'no need to check further
                    End If
                Next i
            End If

        End If 'has any text
    Next c
End Sub
```

I've even manually changed aspects of the sheet it wasn't working on in order to purposefully trigger it, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: What does it do instead of work?  Nothing happens?  You get an error?  Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72452427/478884

Comment: Does it work when you step thru it? If not, where does your logic stop doing what you expect?

Comment: Apologies for not specifying. When I run it on certain sheets, nothing happens at all. No error, no execution. When I run it on other sheets, it works correctly.

Comment: Identify a single cell where you'd expect an outcome from your code, then step through your code while it's reviewing that cell.  Which tests fail and which pass?  How does that differ from what you expect?  We don't have your worksheet, so it's difficult to suggest anything concrete.

Comment: ...worth noting your code checks every cell on every row in the specified range - no need to do that since you can stop checking any row once one cell in that row meets your criteria.